# How can I get the embeddings from a list of words in Python?

Tags: python, vector, word-embedding

Is there a way to get the word embeddings from a list of words to find the semantically relationships between the words?

For example, I have the following list:

```
words = ['one','two','three','football','game','player']
```

I tried to convert my list to `numpy` array vectors through `CountVectorizer` from `sklearn`, the result was a numpy array of ones and zeros, but that is obviously wrong.

Answer (score -1):

You should look word2vec algo:

https://towardsdatascience.com/creating-word-embeddings-coding-the-word2vec-algorithm-in-python-using-deep-learning-b337d0ba17a8

or you can use Gensim lib for word2vec in Python :

https://stackabuse.com/implementing-word2vec-with-gensim-library-in-python/